# Programmatically highlighting element in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I am creating a presentation using latex and beamer. I plan to have a roadmap shown at certain points in the presentation. To this purpose, I have defined

```
\newcommand{\roadmapframe}[1]{
\begin{frame}
\label{roadmap_frame}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
Roadmap:

% if #1 (first argument) is not defined, print the whole thing. 
%  Otherwise highlight only the one passed as #1. How to do this?

\begin{itemize}
\item<1> El 1
\item<1> El2 
\item<0> El3

\end{frame}

}
```

I would like to behave it this way: If I call `\roadmap`, then all three items are printed with full opacity. If I call `\roadmap{2}`, then only the 2 element is at full opacity and the other two are transparent.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{maxroad}

\newcommand{\roadmapframe}[1][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
        \setcounter{maxroad}{3}
    }{
        \setcounter{maxroad}{#1}
    }
    \begin{frame}<\themaxroad>
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    Roadmap:
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
      \begin{itemize}[<+->]
              \item El 1
              \item El2 
              \item El3
      \end{itemize}
    }{
      \begin{itemize}[<+>]
              \item El 1
              \item El2 
              \item El3
      \end{itemize}
    }
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\roadmapframe

\roadmapframe[1]

\roadmapframe[2]

\roadmapframe[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know whether you want that or what @samcarter posted. This leads to the same like @samcarter's, but you can specify the relations to the number in the optional argument in `\roadmapitem`'s argument.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\newcount\roadmaponly
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\roadmapitem[1]
  {%
    \ifnum\roadmaponly=-1
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \ifnum\roadmaponly#1\relax
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
    \fi
    {\item}{\item<0>}%
  }
\makeatother
\newcommand*\roadmapframe[1][-1]
  {%
    \begin{frame}%
      \roadmaponly=#1
      \setbeamercovered{transparent}%
      Roadmap:

      \begin{itemize}
        \roadmapitem{=0} E13
        \roadmapitem{=1} E1 1
        \roadmapitem{=1} E12
      \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}%
  }

\begin{document}
\roadmapframe[0]
\roadmapframe[1]
\roadmapframe[2]
\end{document}
```